# Keep element centered even when overflowing its container

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I recreated my problem in the snippet below: If you make it **Full page** and drag to decrease the horizontal size of the window the `h1` element doesn't stay centered when it exceeds the bounds of it's container.

Here is a visual:

[image]

Notice after it exceeds its containers bounds it just remains left aligned. 
I would like it to stay centered. Is there a simple CSS fix?

```css
@import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #f3f3f3;
}
.v-cntr {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}
.hdg-wrap {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY( -100% );
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<header class="v-cntr">              <!-- << v-cntr = vertically center -->

  <!-- ----------------------- HEADING WRAPPER ------------------------ -->
  <div class="hdg-wrap">
    <h1>RIDE</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- ------------------------ IMAGE WRAPPER ------------------------- -->
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/xL.svg" alt="Logo">
  </div>
</header>
```

*I'm trying not to change the structure of the HTML*

---

**EDIT:** I'm getting answers attempting to center the image instead of the text behind it. I can see the confusion as both get off center. I will reiterate: My main concern is to **keep the `h1` ( 'ride' text ) element centered in the window as it shrinks.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the text-alignment for `.img-wrap`and center the image inside it  using this CSS.

```
.img-wrap {
  text-align: initial;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

ADDITION after comment: And you can apply the same priciple to the `h1`. Since its parent is already absolutely positioned, I didn't change this and just added

```
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Here's the complete snippet:

```css
@import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.v-cntr {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50%);
}

.hdg-wrap {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY( -100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.img-wrap {
  text-align: initial;
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="v-cntr">
  <!-- << v-cntr = vertically center -->

  <!-- -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - HEADING - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <div class="hdg-wrap">
    <!-- << hdg-wrap = heading wrapper -->
    <h1>RIDE</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- -- - - - - - - - - - - - IMAGE WRAPPER - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/xL.svg" alt="Logo">
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I see this centered the image but my question was about the `h1` element staying centered. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: ah, okay...  well, you can do the same with the `h1` - see my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect. I adapted this to my needs. +1 for grammar correction. It's always nice when it's corrected.

Comment: Main oversight was trying `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute` on the `h1`.

Comment: well, and the centering can't be done with regular text-align, but needs the "double-repositioning" like in my answer

Comment: Why does moving it left 50% then right 50% end up with it centered? It works great, but I'm trying to figure out why this hacky-looking approach is necessary.

Comment: @Sinjai The `left: 50%` is 50% of the *container element's* width, which moves the left edge of the children elements to the exacty middle of the container. Then the `transform: translateX(-50%)` is 50% of the * child* elements width, which means the child elements are moved left by half of their own width, which results in the middle of the child elements being at the middle of the parent element, i.e. centered.